# Set Button Text from a callback

Tags: java, android, button, android-fragments, callback

I don't know why I am struggling with this so bad! I have two fragments that are communicating by an interface. The callback should change some data, then trigger a method to change the text of a button. This is the code for the fragment that *should* be changing button text.

```
    public void updateIngredients(final ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients){
    for (Ingredient I : ingredients) {
        recipe.addIngredients(I);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Ingredients size: " + ingredients.size());
    updateIngredientText();
}

public void updateIngredientText(){
    if(recipe.getIngredients() != null) {
        Button bIng = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.bAddIngredientsToRecipe);
        bIng.setText("Ingredients (" + recipe.getIngredients().size() + ")");
    }
}
```

**NOTE** I am getting the log with expected results. But the button text does not change at all. I am getting no errors.

I have tried running this in a `runOnUiThread`, I have tried running it in `onAttach` and `onResume`. The button id is correct, because I use `bIng` to open the other fragment.

Does anyone know why this is not changing my text of my button?

### Update

I think it has something to do with this. This is the method called to go back to the fragment with the button that needs changed:

```
public interface OnIngredientChangedListener {
    public void onIngredientAdded(ArrayList<Ingredient> i);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnIngredientChangedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnIngredientChangedListener");
    }
}

 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //save button clicked
            //notify AddRecipeActivity that ingredients have been added
            mCallback.onIngredientAdded(selectedArray);
            end();
        }
    });

private void end() {
    //fragment Transaction here
    AddRecipe addRecipe = new AddRecipe();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment_frame, addRecipe).commit();
}
```

I think the problem is I am creating a new instance of my fragment.

Comment: Just to clarify - the callback interface is implemented by the parent `Activity` correct?

Comment: We need more code, I think that your interfaces are not registred to the fragments. Are you sure, that they are fired ?

Comment: @Luser_k Yes, I am absolutely sure. I have logged things out.

Comment: @Luser_k I added more code.